# SQLite for WinRT Failing Windows App Certification Kit

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, windows-runtime

I have a Windows 8.1 WinRT app that I'm developing that I can't seem to get to pass WACK. It is built in release mode, and I've tried both 3.8.5 and 3.8.7.4 versions of the SQLite for Windows Runtime (8.1) Visual Studio extensions.

Here's the message from the WACK results compiled against 3.8.5:

```
◦API __CppXcptFilter in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API __clean_type_info_names_internal in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API __dllonexit in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API _amsg_exit in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API _calloc_crt in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API _except1 in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API _except_handler4_common in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API _initterm in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API _initterm_e in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API _localtime64_s in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API _lock in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API _malloc_crt in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API _msize in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API _onexit in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API _unlock in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API free in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API malloc in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API memcpy in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API memmove in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API memset in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API qsort in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API realloc in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
◦API strncmp in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
```

I've tried everything I can think of, and I can't get it to pass WACK. I've tried just excluding ARM, excluding x64... nothing seems to make this work. What do I need to do to get this official SQLite for Windows Runtime extension to pass the Windows App Certification Kit?

Comment: Well, I decided to try submitting it anyways, and it passed certification with the store... so I suppose this is a red herring? But it still would be nice to pass certification with WACK.

Comment: Sounds like you were using 8.0 WACK rather than 8.1 (or you haven't updated WACK lately).

Comment: I have the same error, re-downloaded and re-installed WACK 8.1 but still the same error? Even with older app versions where this test had passed.

Comment: @PeterTorr Thought about that, so I downloaded the latest Windows 8.1 SDK with WACK 3.4, previously I was on 3.3. Failed on both with same error. 3.4 is the latest version AFAICT. Also, the Windows Phone 8.1 universal version using the same SQLite version passed WACK.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working again, you need to uninstall this Update: KB2976978

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e6b87d0d-102b-4940-bc6d-77cf6acd7abc/msvcr120appdll-and-vccorlib120appdll-not-passes-wack?forum=winappswithnativecode)